# multiple lambdas in python program cause VS Code to report a "problem"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm attempting to run some sample python code from Google's Machine Learning Crash Course. I am trying to use Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

The sample code defines a lambda function that calls the same class method, but with different parameters. VS Code is reporting this as a "problem".

I have simplified the code down to this:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*2

f1 = lambda:foo(1)
f2 = lambda:foo(2)
```

VS Code reports: *Function already defined at line 1.*

Questions:
1) Is this actually an error and if so, why?
2) Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

Answers:
See accepted answer for actual solution

Assigning a lambda to a variable violates pep8. The pylint linter is silent on this, but the PEP8 linter generates: *do not assign a lambda expression, use a def*

Comment: What extensions are you using? That message doesn't come from vscode vanilla with nothing but the MS-provided Python extension enabled.

Comment: @taegyung
Your comment was very helpful. It turns out that the "python" extension was cuasing the problem. See details in italics. I installed "Python for VSCode" and that doesn't generate a problem. However, I don't know what I'm gaining or losing by this change.

_Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Intellisense, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, snippets, and more.
Version: 2019.6.24221
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python_

Comment: Also, I'm using this with Python 3.6.8 64-bit, installed by anaconda

Comment: So are you using ms-python.python or another extension? And who is reporting the problem (i.e. the problem should specify which tool such as Pylint, "python" for the python language server, etc.).

Comment: @BrettCannon Yes, I am using ms-python.python v2019.6.24221
it appears to be generating the message ... if I disable the extension then the message goes away. The program runs even though a "problem" has been reported.

Comment: It comes from this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in the language server](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1365) and has been fixed. Please see the issue on details on how to get the update.